# Entropy of sections in Cuckoo Sandbox analysis report

Tags: sandbox, analysis, malware, entropy

When I submit a file for analysis in Cuckoo Sandbox, I always see at the report under "Section" that every section has Entropy column.

I got values like 0, 7.91863415033, 4.4345104565.

What this entropy mean? I tried to search on Google any information about entropy of section but I didn't find something helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Entropy of a file is calculated based on it's randomness. In other words, more unpredictable a file is, more is the entropy value. The values in Cuckoo Sandbox Analysis report are calculated through Shanon's formula and might range between 0 to 8. More closer the entropy value is to zero, less is the randomness in bytes of file same and vice-versa. It helps in decision making process during the analysis of a sample for it's malicious activity. High value of entropy might mean the file is either encrypted strongly or tightly packed.
For more information, go through the link:
https://www.talentcookie.com/2016/02/file-entropy-in-malware-analysis/